# Restful API for Android development

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

I want to build a mobile application and make an API to get data from it 
I have some knowledge in nodejs and learning express and mongodb but really I don't know the way to make an Rest api and how to make it live online to get data from it in my app development 
I read someone article about heroku but don't know what's it and how to use it
I hope to draw a simple path for me to ccreate it or tell me the arranged points to make it
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is too broad.  I would recommend starting with creating a REST service in a language like Node.js.  Come back here if you get stuck with that, and do show us some code.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start  try adapting a sample to your specific requirement